# Why does an "unknown runtime error" occur while executing End(xlDown) in VBScript?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Why does an "unknown runtime error" occur while executing `End(xlDown)` in VBScript?

```
Dim objExcel, objSheet, pbjPath, objBook
objPath="C:\Users\Documents\automateexcel.xls"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objPath)
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "Punter"
objExcel.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1,1).Value = "14"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

The Line `objExcel.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1,1).Value = "14"`  is written to fill first empty cell in the 1st column with value 14. I am able to hard code into any cells in the sheet. But this `xlDown` approach to fill empty cell is causing unknown runtime error.

> C:\Try\automateexcel.vbs(9, 1)
>   Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Unknown runtime error

Comment: `objSheet.Range("A1")...`

Comment: No improvement Scott. objSheet.Range("A1") still throws the same unknown error

Comment: This doesn't address your problem, but don't you want `.Offset(1,0).Value = "14"` (offset 0 columns)?

Comment: Does Column A have data in at least row 2?  If not you are going to the bottom of the page and trying to go one line more.  Try starting at the bottom and going up instead:  `objSheet.Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1,1).Value = "14"`

Comment: vbscript has no idea what `xlDown` is. Put `Option Explicit` on top.

Comment: `.End(xlDown)` -> `.End(-4121)`

Answer (score -3):

```
    Dim objExcel As Object, objSheet As Worksheet, pbjPath As Object, objBook As Object
    Dim rcount As Long

    objPath = "C:\Users\Documents\automateexcel.xls"

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objPath)
    Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    objSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Punter"
    rcount = objSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If rcount = 1 Then objSheet.Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Value = "14" Else _
        objSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = "14"

    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: That won't resolve the problem, but will raise different (additional) errors, because VBScript doesn't support typed variable definitions (`Dim variable As type`).